# POST ничего не передает

Tags: php, post

Вчера буквально все работало, а сегодня с небольшими изменениями уже ни черта не работает.

```
    <form method="POST" action="test.php">
       <input type="file" name="file"/>
       <input type="submit" value="test post"/>
    </form>
```

php

```
echo $_FILES['file']['name'];
```

пишет предупреждение!

> Notice: Undefined index: file in test.php on line 2

Все же в порядке да? Не понимаю что не так, может сервер лагает, что еще может быть ума не приложу

Comment: `var_dump($_FILES);`

Comment: enctype у формы пропущен.

Comment: @Мелкий Огромное спасибо!!! совсем из головы вылетело

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В теге `<form >` добавь параметр `enctype="multipart/form-data"`
[Почитать](http://htmlbook.ru/html/form/enctype)